# How do we do pre-calculations in Druid?

Tags: druid

I have more than 10TB of data ingested to Druid every day, The data format is:

```
srcIP,DestIP,Traffic
```

There would be some frequent queries, such as:

```
to get the max/min/average of traffic every minute
```

Actually we have about 100K records ingested by Druid every minute. So I need to pre-calculate the metrics on every minute otherwise the query would be slow.

Therefore is there any efficient way I can very quickly pre-calculate min/max/ave of traffic for every minute?

Also, the user may like to get the `min/max/average` of traffic by hour or half day.

Answer (score 0):

For calculating min/max/average I think druid is efficient enough to calculate and cache the results for you if there is no data change later.
Even if you will do this at the ingestion time, its still going to take more resources than what druid might take for min/max/average.

You can consider optimising druid config to work efficiently for your use case, eg. granularity of data, aggregation or segment size.

Comment: thank you, do you have example of how to pre-calculating average and min/max in  data ingestion time please?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [TYPE](http://druid.io/docs/latest/development/extensions-contrib/time-min-max.html) min and max

```
  "type": "**timeMax**",
  "type": "**timeMin**”,
```

And for aggregation on 30 minute you need to [groupBy](http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/granularities.html)

```
 granularity":"**thirty_minute**"
```

for [average](http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/post-aggregations.html) ...